# Gender is not a member of the user table?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using following query to find gender of app user.

**q=select gender from user where uid=user_id**

but the output is

**"error": {
    "message": "(#602) gender is not a member of the user table.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 602
  }**

I have seen gender in user table on facebook api,
where is the problem??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gender is represented as "sex" column in users table.
    you can do like this : q = select sex from user where uid=user_id.

For more reference check this :  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/